# Top Margin does not act like I expect.. why?

Tags: html, css

So ive been doing html for a little while now.. but I keep running into issues when I use margins. This causes me to usually just use padding.

Anyway, let me give you an example of something I am working on currently.

http://vasoshield.xcsit.com/index.html

Main structure :

```
<div id="main">
   <div id="header">
       <div id="mainNav">
            main navigation...
       </div>
   </div>
   <div id="content">
        page content...
   </div>
</div>



#main { 
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 745px;
    padding-left: 175px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    background: url(../images/white_bg.jpg) no-repeat top left;
    position: relative;
}

#header {   
    height: 210px; 
}
#mainNav { margin-top: 175px;  }
```

The problem is.. I put margin-top: 150px on the "mainNav" div.. and instead of pushing down 150px from "header" div.. the whole page gets moved down. So the "main" div actualy gets pushed down 150px.. I dont understand why!! If I use padding-top: 150px for "mainNav" div, it actually uses the "header" div to push down from.

Does my question make sense?

I am sure there is some sort of rule I just dont know about. Thanks ahead of time!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You're dealing with *collapsing margins*.**

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

In short, the top margin of #main and #header are next to (adjoining) the margin of #mainNav.  Such vertically adjoining margins are generally collapsed; they form one combined margin.  Compare this to td borders with `border-collapse: collapsed` -- these too become just one border, with width equal to the thickest border.

Only vertical margins collapse, and they only collapse if they're adjoining and they're not *special*.  See  the spec for full details, but things like absolute positioning, floating, and a few other things will prevent margins from collapsing.

For example, you could set `#header { padding-top:1px; }`, or you apply one of the spec-described cases which prevent borders from adjoining (such as floating the element).  Note that floating and the other cases prevent margins from collapsing to simplify the spec: you're entering complex territory, for little gain.

Your fallback option of using padding instead of margin (or applying any kind of intermediate spacing, like the 1px padding I described earlier) are better choices; they impact the rest of your layout fairly minimally, whereas introducing floats and/or absolute positioning can cause weird interactions once pages get complex (in particular once you start considering printing scenarios).

Comment: cool.  thats explains the logic behind it.  basically if i can prevent the margins from collapsing my problem is solved.  adding "overflow: hidden" i assume causes the div to be 'special' in turn preventing collapse ( just like border or padding etc would do ).  am i right?

Comment: Yeah, adding `#header { overflow: hidden; }` will work fine and is quite a bit simpler than my idea of setting a tiny top-padding.  Good idea!

Answer (score 1):

Well.. simply adding overflow: hidden to the "main" container works..  dont ask me why!

Comment: 'overflow: hidden' works because that's part of the intended behavior of the box model spec. See the rule set shown below "Example X" on http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#collapsing-margins

...Setting the overflow property to anything other than 'visible' establishes the element as a "flow root" which essentially means it establishes its own formatting context. This trick (not a hack!) is super handy for containing floats & preventing collapsing margins.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no content in the `header` div before the `mainNav` div, the margin is the first thing that the browser needs to take into account, so it looks as if the whole page gets shifted down. I suggest to add `1px solid red` borders to all divs so you can see which one goes where.

Comment: Actually, adding `border: 1px solid red` will prevent margins from collapsing ;-). That'll make debugging complex... What you want is `outline: 1px dotted red;` -- that'll just superimpose an outline without modifying layout (works in all common browsers except IE7 or older)

Comment: that is REALY nice to know. border usually messes up layout because i usually float stuff pixel perfect.. so 1 pixel too much throws off the layout.

Comment: @Roeland: there are many more ways to debug CSS layouts. You can also use different background colors or images or whatever. Only having an attitude will not help :)

Comment: Speaking of debugging, I'm sure most people have heard of Firebug, a web-dev's best friend, but just in case... Firebug's great! It's a great help since it'll let you tweak css-rules on the fly, and highlight element positions, compute offsets etc etc all on a live, JS-enabled page.

Comment: yah i use it, but i prefer "web developer".  though i do use both.

Answer (score -1):

try to put your main div position in position:absolute; It will work I think. I do not know the reason

Comment: This works same reason as my comment above regarding 'overflow: hidden'. Using 'position: absolute' also establishes the element as a new "flow root", but 'position: absolute' isn't nearly as good of a solution for this particular problem as it can have more unintended consequences for the layout.